# Why My statement is not writing value to hidden field using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

`$('#myhidde').attr("value",data[0]['MODE']);`

Iam calling ajax page which returns me json data 
after getting the data from JSON results when i alert also iam able to  see the value but iam not able to write to hidden field .What would be the reason .Dying for 2hrs

Comment: `myhidde` ?? should that be `myhidden`?? also, you aren't trying to hook an onchange event to the hidden field are you? because that won't fire when the value is changed programatically in JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: @konerak :It gives me the expected  Value  but when i write it is not writing

Comment: There are 3 answers here stating that `.val()` needs to be used instead of `.attr('value', ... )`. Can someone please explain to me why that would be the case for a `<input type="hidden"/>`?

Comment: oh, one other thing... are you "checking" if the value is set in **Firebug**? I can't recall exactly how I did it, but I did find once that certain calls to update the value of a hidden field didn't show up right away *in Firebug*... but were actually being applied. e.g. if this was the case, type this in the address bar: `javascript:alert($('#myhidde').val());` to see if it was actually set.

Comment: @scunliffe:I am Able to get the Value with the above approach what you said .But when i see the View source it is blank .would that get submitted to serrver side if i dont see any value in the viewsource .Does it gets submitted to php

Comment: @scunliffe: That was able to see in the POST  at server side in php Script so my problem is solved

Comment: @Someone - you will not see the value in the *right click > view source* (the source isn't live, its static from the original load), and you **may** not see it in firebug, but I highly expect the setting of the value worked, and will submit.

Comment: I updated my comments in an answer below if it helps clarify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm summing up all my comments in an answer here:

Be aware of the following when trying to debug hidden/input field interaction.

1. View-Source in browsers shows you the "static" HTML that was part of the original HTTPResponse
   1.1 If your browser supports it, try selecting text on the page around the element and choose "view selection source" this typically reveals "up-to-date" source
2. If you try to use an onchange event handler on a field to alert the new value after you've set it programatically via JavaScript, it will NOT alert the value because the onchange event only fires when the user interacts with the field to change the value
3. Firebug *may* not appear to update the value of a hidden field under special circumstances (I've witnessed this, but been unable to find a reliable test case to submit a bug) - get a 2nd verification from JavaScript or submitting the page
4. Try changing the type attribute temporarily from "hidden" to "text" so that you can *see* the value when it changes

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for hidden field:

```
$('#myhidde').val(data[0]['MODE']);
```

Comment: Any documentation on why this works then vs. setting the "value" attribute?

Comment: @Someone: Is your code within `ready` handler? Are you using the `form` tag? What is the error you get then?

Comment: @Someone, the syntax is correct, so there must be something wrong with the `data` object or with the HTML code

Comment: @HARMEN:if i try to write the same value in to a text field it is being written

Answer (score 1):

First check what is inside your data object: `console.log( data );`

Then, use the correct syntax:

```
$('#myhidde').val( data[0]['MODE'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
$('#myhidde').val(data[0]['MODE']);
```

Comment: @Someone - what error are you getting in the javascript console?

Comment: if i try to write the same value in to a text field it is being written